# how to specify an object without using its attributes

Tags: c++, object

I am learning object oriented programming.
To know which object is being destroyed, I want to add some code in the destructor of a class and use an attribute to do it.
For example-

```
class player{
public:
string name;
int health;

~player(){
cout<<name<<" destroyed";
}
};
```

In this example, name correctly helps me identify the object which is being destroyed.
But if there weren't any such attributes which could help me know which object was being destroyed, what should be done.
Is there a way to print the object's name itself. ( i.e. if I create a `player enemy;` then enemy is what I mean to say by name)

Comment: Maybe `cout << this << " destroyed\n"`?  And if it is important to see information when streamed to output, maybe you should consider overloading `operator <<` for your `player` class.  Then it wouldn't matter where you want to see output, whether it is in the destructor or somewhere else.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie thanks, that complete answered my question. I haven't studied operator overloading and this pointer yet. but I'm going to

Comment: No there is not. Variable names identify objects for the compiler (and for the programmer reading the code) but they don't exist in the compiled program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be versatile, you can overload `operator <<` instead of focusing solely on the destructor and outputting bits and pieces of your class attributes.

Here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

class player {
    std::string name;
    int health;
public:
    player(const std::string& n, int h) : name(n), health(h) {}
    ~player() { std::cout << "Destroying the following: " << *this << "\n"; }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const player& p);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const player& p)
{
    os << p.name << " " << p.health;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    player p1("Joe", 1);
    player p2("Sam", 2);
    std::cout << p1 << "\n" << p2 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Joe 1
Sam 2
Destroying the following: Sam 2
Destroying the following: Joe 1
```

You can follow what was done by looking at some [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019).